# I need to make a Windows CE 7 frame grabber using DirectShow

Tags: windows-ce, frame, directshow, samplegrabber

I need to make a Windows CE 7 frame grabber using DirectShow.
All examples on the internet are pointing to the custom implementation of ISampleGrabber that is deprecated but still available. I need any solution that works.
I tried the solution from this link [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28790/Creating-Custom-DirectShow-SampleGrabber-Filter-fo) but didn't worked.
On my BeagleBoard (Arm 8) with Windows CE 7 the ISampleGrabber simply is not registered.

What should I do? Is there any other good working example ?

One more requirement is to make the most responsive camera capture possible.
Many sources are pointing to use the ISampleGrabber but it is deprecated.

Comment: What exactly did not work? Did you manage to create that filter and connect it to your video stream?

Comment: This is exactly what I need http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28790/Creating-Custom-DirectShow-SampleGrabber-Filter-fo but it needs to implement the CTransInPlaceFilter that doesn't exist on Win CE 7 and I can't compile it.

Comment: Have you built the base classes project where this class is defined?